# Hide dropdownMenu after clicking its item

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with navbar from bootstrap. My code looks like this (there's nothing important in CSS, I think):

```
let pic = require("../../images/pic.png");

function NavBar(props) {
  const admin = props.isAdmin;
  const showTabs =
props.isCategory &&
props.localization !== "/" &&
props.localization !== "/su";

  return (
<div>
  {/*here is big version of navbar without dropdown - nothing important*/}

  <div className="small">
    <Navbar className="Navbar" variant="dark" sticky="top" expand="md">
      {brandBar(100)}

      {showTabs && (
        <div className="categoryInfoContainer">{props.categoryInfo}</div>
      )}

      <div className="mainContainer">
        {showTabs && (
          <Navbar.Toggle
            aria-controls="navbarDiv"
            className="dropdownBtn"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarDiv"
          />
        )}
        <Navbar.Collapse id="navbarDiv" className="justify-content-end">
          <div className="bookmarks">
            <Nav variant="tabs">
              <Nav.Link
                active={props.location.pathname === "/"}
                as={Link}
                to="/"
              >
                Main page
              </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link
                active={props.location.pathname === "/link1"}
                as={Link}
                to="/link1"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="justify-content-end navbar-collapse collapse show"
              >
                link1
              </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link
                active={props.location.pathname === "/link2"}
                as={Link}
                to="/link2"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target=".navbarDiv.show"
              >
                link2
              </Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link
                active={props.location.pathname === "/link3"}
                as={Link}
                to="/about"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="navbarDiv.justify-content-end.navbar-collapse.collapse.show"
              >
                link3
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
          </div>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </div>
    </Navbar>
  </div>
</div>
  );
}

function brandBar(height) {
  return (
<div className="logoContainer">
  <Link to="/">
    <Navbar.Brand>
      <img
        src={pic}
        width="auto"
        height={height}
        className="d-inline-block align-top brand"
        alt="logo"
      />
    </Navbar.Brand>
  </Link>
</div>
  );
}
```

When I click any item from menu redirecting works ok, but menu doesn't hide. In "data-target" I've left two options which I tried, but none of them worked - menu is still visible. I also tried versions like *"#navbarDiv"* etc. How can I handle closing dropdown after clicking its menu? I've spent many hours with it, maybe I'm not seeing something obvious...

Some pics that show the problem:

[navbar closed...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9vRr.png)

[I'm on /link2, I open the navbar, everything is good...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVKK8.png)

[I've redirected correctly to /link1, but after redirecting navbar is still open 
- that's the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjRAT.png)

Comment: Hi, Can you show me the functions, to understand it or Can you share that simple code example in Codesandbox. So, that i can check

Comment: @szysza, welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please more details about your `dropDownMenu`? I don't see any drop-down added in there. Can you actually share an image perhaps? You can edit the question to add that image in the question.

Comment: @JeyanthKanagaraj thanks for your attention - I've edited my post, attached more code and images. If you need more info - please tell me

Comment: @NagarajTantri thanks for your attention - I've edited my post, attached more code and images. If you need more info - please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things which I think you should add/change.

- Ensure to add `collapseOnSelect` on `NavBar` to make it collapse when you select the `Nav.Link`
- Ensure to add/change `Nav.Link` to have either `href` or `eventKey` attribute to enable the collapse on select feature

Here is a working code which has been added to do the needful:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

function MyNavBar(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="small">
        <Navbar collapseOnSelect className="Navbar" variant="dark" sticky="top" expand="md">
          <div className="mainContainer">
            <Navbar.Toggle
              aria-controls="navbarDiv"
              className="dropdownBtn"
              data-toggle="collapse"
              data-target="#navbarDiv"
            />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="navbarDiv">
              <div className="bookmarks">
                <Nav variant="tabs">
                  <Nav.Link
                    href="#home"
                  >
                    Main page
              </Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link
                    eventKey="link1"
                  >
                    link1
              </Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link
                    eventKey="lin2"
                  >
                    link2
              </Nav.Link>
                  <Nav.Link
                    eventKey="link3"
                  >
                    link3
              </Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
              </div>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
          </div>
        </Navbar>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyNavBar;
```

Comment: Thank You so much, eventKey do the thing.